# Blow-up of a Pencil of Cubic Curves (Miranda's basic theory of elliptic surfaces)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, intersection-theory, blowup

In Rick Miranda's "The basic theory of elliptic surfaces" the Example (I.5.1) see page 7 on a pencil of plane curves contains an argument Inot understand yet:

Let $C_1$ be a smooth cubic curve in $\mathbb{P^2}$ and let $C_2$ be any other cubic. By intersection theory and Bezout's theorem the intersection number $C_1 \cdot C_2$ is $9$. We form a pencil $P \subset \mathbb{P^2} $ generated by $C_1$ and $C_2$; in english that is a $\mathbb{P^1}$-family of curves (or more generally divisors) $[ \lambda C_1 + \mu C_2 ]$, which has $9$ base points $x_1,..., x_9$ . This gives only a rational map to $\mathbb{P^1}$. After blowing them up the fundamental locus of this rational map is resolved and we obtain a honest morphism $\pi: X \to \mathbb{P^1}$ where $X= Blowup(P)_{x_1,..., x_9}$ is the blowup of the pencil $P$ in these $ 9 $ points.

Then it is claimed that the canonical class of $X$ is $-C_1$ and in particular that this implies that $K_X^2= (-C_1)^2 =0$.

How to check that the canonical class of $X$ equals $-C_1$ and why does it have as consequence self-intersection number zero? The divisor $-C_1$ is definietely not vertical and therefore I not see why it's interesection with itself should vanish.

Answer (score 2):

Note that such a blow-up $X$ can be represented by a degree $(1,3)$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^2$, so you can see $K_X=-C$ by adjunction formula. We have $K_X^2=0$ because $X$ is a minimal elliptic surface (see  III.21 in Beauville's Complex Algebraic Surfaces).

Comment: Could you explain how to check that this blowup $X$ is represented by a degree $(1,3)$ hypersurface in $ \mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^2$? Intuitively that sounds reasonable, how can it be formalized? Idea/guess: Is the blow-up $X$ considered as hyperspace in $ \mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^2$ precisely the vanishing scheme of the bihomogeneous polynomial $Z_0 \cdot F_1(Y)+Z_1 F_2(Y) \in \mathbb{C}[Z_0,Z_1, Y_0, Y_1, Y_2]$ where $F_i$ defines $C_i$ in $P^2$. If yes, how to see it formally?